# Bash skipping iteration in for

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, iteration

I have to write an macro that gets few arguments to it. for example ./macro.sh -wrongone -f filename -wrongone.
I have to catch the wrong ones and list them and make required operation on the valid ones. Here is my code:

```
for i in "${ArrayOfParameters[@]}"
do
    tmp=$[tmp+1]
    case "${i}" in

    "-h" | "--help")
        help
        ;;

    "-f")   
        a="${ArrayOfParameters[i+1]}"
        echo $a
        i=$[i+1]            
        ;;          

    *)
        echo -e "${red}Parameter ${i} is wrong!${NC}"
        ;;
    esac

done
```

My problem is that I do not know how to make 'filename' to be skipped by default operation of the switch :(. Every time I get error that filename is wrong parameter. I was thinking about skipping one iteration. Something like that in C++.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
if(i==3)
i=4;
```

I would like to get something like that in Bash but no idea how to do it.
Tried

```
for (( i=0; i<=5; i++ ))
a="${ArrayOfParameters[i]}"
```

but it was returning me all the time numbers not the strings.
I would be really gratefull for helpfull answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to skip the *next* item after you find `-f`, right? If that's the case, you can use a more C-looking syntax and play with the array *index*, rather than with the array *contents*

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ArrayOfParameters=("-hello" "-howdy" "-foo bar" "-f" "-something else")

for ((i=0; i <= ${#ArrayOfParameters[@]}; i++))
do
    item=${ArrayOfParameters[i]}
    echo "Studying item number ${i} (value: ${item})"
    case "${item}" in
        "-f")   
           echo "Found -f. Skipping next."  
           ((i++))
           ;;          
        *)
           echo "NOT skipping ${item}"
           ;;
    esac
done
```

You'll see that it skips the item after `-f`:

```
Studying item number 0 (value: -hello)
NOT skipping -hello
Studying item number 1 (value: -howdy)
NOT skipping -howdy
Studying item number 2 (value: -foo bar)
NOT skipping -foo bar
Studying item number 3 (value: -f)
Found -f. Skipping next.
Studying item number 5 (value: )
NOT skipping
```

Comment: Hmm though it still doesnt work as I intended :/. Will use other solutions :P then.

Comment: @user3593720, If you edit your question explaining why doesn't this work as intended, maybe we can work on it **;-)**

Comment: The problem is still the same. Lets say that my third argument is -f fourth name of the file and fifth lets say -g. I want program to skip fourth argument, because if it wont skip it the *) (default) will write me an message. I did everything like in your code but still *) is writing that the item was not skipped >.<.

Comment: @user3593720, do you mean it still prints the fourth argument (name of file)?  Because I've tried with `ArrayOfParameters=("-hello" "-howdy" "-foo bar" "-f" "-something else"  "-g" "whatever")`  and it does skip the item after `-f`, _jumping_ from `-f` to `-g` (without showing `-something else`). Or do you want to completely stop the loop right when it finds `-f` ? (you'd need a `break` for that) My tests are on Ubuntu 12.04, bash 4.2.25 . Maybe you can edit your question and add the new code?

Comment: Oh Nvm I have fixed it :P Iam dumb! For and <= was the problem just did not notice it ealier that I wrote such stupid thing and was searching everywhere only not there.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to your coding problem, but I think you should do yourself a favor and use `getopts` (see [here for a good tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)).  Handling parameters is usually messy and there are a lot of corner cases, so rolling your own is not always a good idea.

Comment: GNU/Linux `getopt(1)` is much more versatile than `getopts`. It's not shipped with every system though, especially not in the BSD family, but it's usually easy enough to install with a package manager.

Comment: Looking for easiest solution. Additionally no idea what system will user use so have to write as much universal script as it is possible.

Comment: I see.  Still, note that contrary to `getopt`, `getopts` is part of bash and has been so for a long time.  So if you can at least rely on the fact that your script requires bash, you should be safe.  If you can't rely on the fact it's bash, you will need to be careful of a good many things (arithmetic expansion, double quotes in if etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to use a flag variable that you set to `true` if '-f' matches and at the beginning of your for loop, check if that flag is set, set it to false and use `continue`.

```
skipNext=false
for i in "${ArrayOfParameters[@]}"
do
    if $skipNext
    then
        skipNext=false
        continue
    fi
    tmp=$[tmp+1]
    case "${i}" in
        "-h" | "--help")
            help
            ;;
        "-f")
            skipNext=true
            a="${ArrayOfParameters[i+1]}"
            echo $a
            i=$[i+1]            
            ;;
        *)
            echo -e "${red}Parameter ${i} is wrong!${NC}"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a 'while' loop instead. Use 'shift' to move the argument pointer to the next argument, then use "$1" to read the argument you want. You have complete control over the arguments that way:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -f) shift
        FILE="$1"
    ;;
    -h|*) help
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```